# How to compare two arrays of objects and get the values that differ in React?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, changelog

I am trying to do a changelog for my website.

For expample, I have the initial array, call it `initArray`:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "val1": "2023-08-28",
        "val2": 1,
        "val3": "",
        "val4": "",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "val1": "2023-08-28",
        "val2": 2,
        "val3": "",
        "val4": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "val1": "2023-08-28",
        "val2": 0,
        "val3": "",
        "val4": ""
    }
]
```

And then, I have the second array, call it `changedArray`:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "val1": "2023-08-28",
        "val2": 1,
        "val3": "test",
        "val4": "test1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "val1": "2023-08-28",
        "val2": 2,
        "val3": "test2",
        "val4": "test3"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "val1": "2023-08-28",
        "val2": 0,
        "val3": "",
        "val4": ""
    }
]
```

So, I need to find the values that were changed and output the names of these values and the values themselves. How can this be done?

The expected outcome would be like:

```
[
    {
        "changedValue": "val3", 
        "previousValue": "", 
        "newValue": "test"
    },
    //And so on...
]
```

The number of elements in the arrays is constant, there can't be deleted or added elements – only changed.

Comment: So what would be the expected outcome for your example? How do you identify, if two objects are the same (ie how to identifiy, if an object was removed or added to the array, or if an existing element was updated)

Comment: @derpirscher, Added clarifications to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array#reduce` function to loop over the *array* of *objects* and compare the values with the corresponding object in the new array.

```js
const compare = (arr1, arr2) => 
   arr1.reduce((acc, next, idx) => {
      Object.entries(next).forEach(([key, val]) => {
         const newValue = arr2[idx]?.[key];
         if (newValue && val !== newValue) {
            acc.push({
               changedValue: key,
               previousValue: val,
               newValue,
            })
         }
      });
      
      return acc;
   }, []);
   
const data1=[{"val1":1,"val2":"2023-08-28","val3":1,"val4":"","val5":"",},{"val1":2,"val2":"2023-08-28","val3":2,"val4":"","val5":""},{"val1":3,"val2":"2023-08-28","val3":0,"val4":"","val5":""}];
const data2=[{"val1":1,"val2":"2023-08-28","val3":1,"val4":"test","val5":"test1"},{"val1":2,"val2":"2023-08-28","val3":2,"val4":"test2","val5":"test3"},{"val1":3,"val2":"2023-08-28","val3":0,"val4":"","val5":""}];
   
console.log(compare(data1, data2));
```